# Assigning Dynamic Cell Value to Variable

Tags: python, class, dynamic

As the title says, I am looking to assign `Cell(x,y).value` to a variable so that whenever I call it, the variable automatically sees what internal values (`x` and `y` in this case) the class is calling, so that I can use this variable in multiple places throughout my program.

To get a sense of what I'm trying to do, here is an example (I'm interfacing with Excel):

```
l1 = 1
while not Cell(l1, 6).is_empty():
  if not Cell(l1, 7).is_empty():
    referent = Cell(l1, 6).value
    cellval = Cell(l1, i).value
    for i in range(15, 22):
      if i == 15:
        cellval = function_call(referent)
      else:
        cellval = other_function_call(referent)
  l1 += 1

Cell(x, y) = Cell(row,column)
```

Comment: I really don't follow. Presumably `Cell(x,y)` is an object which is linked to a cell in an Excel spreadsheet. `Cell(x,y).value` seems like the value that is in the cell at that point in time in which it is assigned to some variable (`referent` in your example). But then `referent` would be something like a simple int or float or string. *It* wouldn't automatically update as the spreadsheet changes.

Comment: Looking at this again, the question makes no sense. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it makes no sense. VBA itself has an arguably bad feature of `default property` of an object (which for a `range` object is its `value`) . This allows you to treat a range variable which is bound to a cell as a simple value in an expression, but one which dynamically updates as the program goes on. This is sort of what you wanted. I don't think this is a good idea, even in VBA, and I tend to always use an explicit `.Value` when I want to access a cell's value. I don't think that Python even allows you to use an object variable in such an ambiguous manner.